# Python How to display both String and Integer value from Entrytext tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I Want to display both string and Integer value after entering into the EntryText widget.

I am using below Code and able to display Integer value but not String:

```
 global Input
 Input = int(entrytext1.get())
 print Input
```

If I enter 'q' in entrytext1 get below error:

```
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'
```

If I use below code, it will get below error:

```
global Input
Input = (entrytext1.get())
print Input

 No_SED_MENU_Items = len(SED_MENU_Items)
 print No_SED_MENU_Items
 if (not((Input > 0 ) and (Input <= No_SED_MENU_Items))):
  print('\nInvalid option')
 else:
  SMI = SED_MENU_Items[Input-1]['ID']
  SED_item_select = hex(SMI)[2:].zfill(4)
  FirstByte = SED_item_select[0:2]
  SecByte = SED_item_select[2:4]
  request = '22'+ ' '+FirstByte+' '+SecByte
  print (request)
```

Error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment
```

How Can I fix that, If I type Integer, it should print my request and If I type String, if should only print

Comment: What do you expect to get when you want to convert "q" to an int? Do you want to convert it to an int only when it *can* be converted?

Comment: Yes, It should take both Int and str

Answer (score 0):

You could change `Input` to accept inputs without casting them immediately, but then cast them later on depending on what you want to do with them. This is how you would do that.

```
Input = (entrytext1.get()) #Remove the integer casting

print (str(Input)) #Converts 'Input' to a string
print (int(Input)) #Converts 'Input' to an integer
```

The problem with this is that `Input` is expecting any data type because there is no validation. By removing the data type and casting it later on, you allow anything to be entered. This can cause problems as Python will return a `ValueError` if you try to, for example, convert `'q'` to an integer.

To get past this, you can use `try-except` blocks. Judging from a comment on the OP, this solution is better suited for you, as it allows both integer and string inputs, but only casts if it is possible, removing the chance of an error. I have implemented this in an example function below.

```
def CastIfPossible():
    Input = (entrytext1.get())

    try: #Try converting the input to an integer
        cast_test = int(Input)
        return cast_test #Returns if it is possible

    except ValueError: #If it is not possible
        print ("That was a string, not an integer. Casting is not possible.")
        return Input #Return the original input as a string

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cast_value = CastIfPossible()
    print (cast_value) #Prints both int and str inputs
```

This allows anything to be entered by the user, converts it to an integer if possible, and if not, leaves it as a string.